# How to set up ethernet connection? 16.04 server

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, ethernet

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04. I've connected the Ethernet cable to my desktop, and it seems to have been found, but I can't connect to the Internet.

Here's the output from some commands:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp
```

**ip link**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2. enp3so: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:aa:14:09:90:df brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Where should I go from here?

Comment: What is the result of: `sudo ifdown enp0s25 && sudo ifup -v enp0s25`?

Comment: Error getting hardware address for "enp0s25": No such device

Comment: Actually, I'm getting `interface enp0s25 not configured`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command `ip link` shows that the ethernet interface is *enp3so* which I suspect is actually *enp3s0*; in other words, with a zero, not an oh. Please amend your */etc/network/interfaces* file to read:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
```

Of course, double-check if it is enp3so or enp3s0 and substitute as needed.

Then do:

```
sudo ifdown enp3s0 && sudo ifup -v enp3s0
```

Did you connect?

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually have `enp3s0` in the config, I just entered the results manually and copied it incorrectly. Anyway, I tried ifdown but I get the error `"Unknown interface enp3s0"`. Do yo think this is something to do with me having both `enp0s25` and `enp3s0`?

Comment: Which has the cable attached? That one needs to be declared in */etc/network/interfaces*. Is there any clue here? `sudo ethtool enp3s0` or else: `sudo ethtool enp0s25`

Comment: Okay thanks, appears to be `enp3s0`. I updated _/etc/network/interfaces_, and now `ifdown` is returning with **interface enp3s0 not configured**

Comment: And then does `ifup` succeed?

Comment: Yep! Thanks. It currently fails saying **No DHCPOFFERS received**, but at least I'm getting somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: Is a DHCP server at the other end of the cable? Want to try a static address? Should we look at the ethernet driver?

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend to do the following. First statement will update the dns nameserver and the next two successive commands will bring down and try making up your ethernet.

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ifconfig enp0s25 down
sudo ifconfig enp25 up
```

After that , try the following command to see connection , if something went wrong you can post the output of it as well.

```
ping 8.8.8.8
ping yahoo.com
tracepath google.com
```

Thats it.

Comment: I'm getting a "No such device" error when running `sudo ifconfig enp0s25 down`

Comment: post op of  command **sudo ifconfig**